# GridLayout throws illegal component position

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

By default GridLayout(5,3) would add the components in this way:

```
A B C
D E F
G H I
J K L
M N O
```

To have the components disposed in the following positions:

```
A F K
B G L
C H M
D I N
E J O
```

I have this code:

```
//imports...

public class GridLayoutProblem {

    private static final int NUM_ROWS = 5, NUM_COLMS=3;
    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel buttonPannel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(NUM_ROWS, NUM_COLMS));

    private JButton btnA = new JButton("A");
    private JButton btnB = new JButton("B");
    //same with C, D...
    private JButton btnO = new JButton("O");

    private JComponent[] buttons = {
            btnA, btnB, btnC, btnD, btnE,
            btnF, btnG, btnH, btnI, btnJ,
            btnK, btnL, btnM, btnN, btnO
    };

    public GridLayoutProblem(){
        int i=0;
        for (JComponent button : buttons){
            int index = i%NUM_ROWS*NUM_COLMS+i/NUM_ROWS;
            buttonPannel.add(button,index);
            i++;
        }
        mainPanel.add(buttonPannel);
    }
    //...
```

But it results in:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal component position.

Comment: Add a try-catch around `buttonPannel.add()`. When the exception is thrown print out the index that you calculated and determine where that calculation went wrong.

Comment: Fails in i = 1 index = 3.

Comment: Ok, I changed the whole for each loop to:
`buttonPannel.add(btnB, 3);`
And the exception is thrown again. So the conclusion is that GridLayout does not allow this.

Comment: @Iridrio Did you read the two answers? Codebender already stated *"you cannot skip indexes and add elements to higher index."*.

Comment: @LuxxMiner I dismissed it (my fault) because the reference manual that I follow seems to be wrong. It indicates that you actually can add in an arbitrary index, but you can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a quick test and it seems you cannot skip indexes and add elements to higher index.

So your option is to do something like this,

```
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS*NUM_COLMS; i++){
        int index = i%NUM_COLMS*NUM_ROWS+i/NUM_COLMS; // Note the change in calculation. Just interchange rows and colms from your algo.
        buttonPannel.add(button[index],i);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `buttonPannel.add(button,index);` to `buttonPannel.add(buttons[index]);`. (You don't need a foreach-loop) GridLayout always adds the components like you showed in the first example, but if you can make your calculation for `index` right (see other answer), so it adds it like "A,F,K,B...", you can achieve what you want.

Run the code below to see how the buttons are being added:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

//imports...

public class GridLayoutProblem {

    private static final int NUM_ROWS = 5, NUM_COLMS=3;
    private static JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel buttonPannel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(NUM_ROWS, NUM_COLMS));

    private JButton btnA = new JButton("A");
    private JButton btnB = new JButton("B");
    private JButton btnC = new JButton("C");
    private JButton btnD = new JButton("D");
    private JButton btnE = new JButton("E");
    private JButton btnF = new JButton("F");
    private JButton btnG = new JButton("G");
    private JButton btnH = new JButton("H");
    private JButton btnI = new JButton("I");
    private JButton btnJ = new JButton("J");
    private JButton btnK = new JButton("K");
    private JButton btnL = new JButton("L");
    private JButton btnM = new JButton("M");
    private JButton btnN = new JButton("N");
    private JButton btnO = new JButton("O");

    private JComponent[] buttons = {
            btnA, btnB, btnC, btnD, btnE,
            btnF, btnG, btnH, btnI, btnJ,
            btnK, btnL, btnM, btnN, btnO
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GridLayoutProblem();
    }

    public GridLayoutProblem(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS * NUM_COLMS; i++) {
                    int index = i%NUM_COLMS*NUM_ROWS+i/NUM_COLMS;
                    buttonPannel.add(buttons[index]);
                    frame.revalidate();
                    frame.repaint();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
        mainPanel.add(buttonPannel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```